# HTTP_REFERER in htaccess not working in Internet Explorer ( IE)

Tags: .htaccess, internet-explorer, http-referer

I have htaccess file with the following rule

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}   !(inbox/view/\?mail_id).*  [NC]   
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

This would ensure that the file link will only open if clicked on pages with 'inbox','view' or '?mail' in its url. It's working in major browsers except IE . IE8 and IE9 throws 403 Forbidden Access error.

Any response is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You should already _know_ that referer is absolutely unreliable … your IE you’re testing with probably just send _none_, and so this house-of-cards “access protection system” you are trying to dilettantishly build here comes tumbling down.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you should be using

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}   !(inbox|view|\?mail_id).*  [NC]   
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

And I suppose that the Forbidden you are receiving is from the [F] in your rule.

Comment: thanks but that is exactly my code you cited. the problem is specific to IE because other browsers abide by that condition.

Comment: This isn't very helful since this code is the same as OP's one.

Comment: No the code is different. The OP has `inbox/view/` with slashes where as this answer has `inbox|view|` with pipes.